# Getting process list in android with "top -n 1" command from 6.0 onwards

Tags: android

I am trying to get the list of processes in android with the top command("top -n 1).

on executing the command with "adb shell top -n 1", it list many processes but when I tried the same with test code as follows:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process mProcess;

try {

    mProcess = rt.exec("top -n 1");

    mProcess.waitFor();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

            mProcess.getInputStream()));

    String line = null;

    boolean exit = false;

    while (!exit) {

        line = in.readLine();

        Log.i(TAG,"line val is: "+line);

    }
}catch(...)
```

and the out put is only 2 processes along with testapp as follows:

```
line val is: User 0%, System 0%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%

line val is: User 0 + Nice 0 + Sys 0 + Idle 1 + IOW 0 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 0 = 1


line val is:   PID USER     PR  NI CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY Name

line val is: 22237 u0_a550  20   0   0% R     1   4532K   1264K  ta top

line val is: 15374 u0_a550  20   0   0% S    22 1190596K  59716K  ta test.myapp.testprocesslist
```

What I observed is it listed only the same USER id values.

How can I get all the processes through code? I hope in positive way.

The same code works fine in below 6.0 devices.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried same thing but not working, i also tried "top -m 10 -n 1 > /sdcard/fileName.txt". That also not working